# Global publish settings in meteor

Tags: meteor

In meteor, is there a way to run something before every publish. Something like (pseudo) Metoer.onBeforePublish?

A use case would be to add a protection layer to all the publish functions, for example:

```
if (!this.userId) {
  return this.ready()
}
```

Comment: You could create a function that wraps the callback with this check and use it instead of directly using `publish`. You can even implement such mechanism that calls `onBeforePublish` callbacks yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MasterAM comment, here is my implementation:

```
pub = function(name) {
  var cb = Array.prototype.pop.call(arguments)
  var args = Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1, -1)
    if(Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.publish(name, function(args){
        if (!this.userId) {
          return this.ready()
        }
      })
      cb(args)
    }
}
```

and call it like so:

```
pub('taxes', query, options, function(){
  Taxes.find(query, options)
})
```

Thanks!